# display: block a random img from wihtin a div

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of JPEGs inside a DIV and want jQuery to randomly pick one of the IMGs on page load to give it an inline display: block class - all IMGs on load have display:none. This way only 1 of the X number of IMGs will be in view. How can I achieve this?

```
<style>
.randomJPEG img { display: none; }
</style>

<div class="randomJPEG">
<img src="01.jpg"/>
<img src="02.jpg"/>
<img src="03.jpg"/>
<img src="04.jpg"/>
<img src="05.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a dynamic example for you, using the `Math.random()` method to choose from your elements. It takes the number of `img` children of a `div` with class `randomJPEG` to calculate a random element.

```js
$(function() {
    var items = $('div.randomJPEG img').length;
    var rnd   = Math.floor(Math.random() * items);
    
    $("div.randomJPEG img").eq(rnd).css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
div.randomJPEG img {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="randomJPEG">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/fff000/000000"/>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/000fff/000000"/>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/ff00ff/000000"/>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/f0f0f0/000000"/>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150/f0000f/000000"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks perfect! Thanks N.M. Will accept it when I can in a few mins.

Answer (score 0):

### jQuery

```
$('img:nth-child('+Math.floor(Math.random()*5+1)+')').css('display','inline-block')
```

### Vanilla

```
document.querySelector('img:nth-child('+Math.floor(Math.random()*5+1)+')').style.display = 'inline-block';
```

Comment: Thanks levi - but your jQuery throws an error - syntax isnt right I dont think